# Is it good practice to create a React component just to hold props?

Tags: reactjs

Is it considered a good idea to simply have a Component in React that renders nothing and performs no logic, but rather just behaves as a "container" for its props?

The main reason I bring this up is for organizational purposes. Instead of using a `<div>` element, I thought it would be better to give it a more meaningful name. In my particular case, I'm trying to create a Tabs component, which is designed to render Tabs and their respective contents.

The Tabs component is going to extract out the data and render it properly. As you can see in the example below, The `<TabItem>` component really does nothing and is simply a `<div>` element that has been renamed.

```
<TabContainer>
    <TabItem label="firstTab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem label="secondTab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    </TabItem>
</TabContainer>
```

If I were to use `div`'s instead, it would look like:

```
<TabContainer>
    <div label="firstTab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    </div>
    <div label="secondTab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    </div>
</TabContainer>
```

Comment: You can take a look to: https://styled-components.com/, I think you are looking for it.
But you can do it yourself, as you did.

Comment: If you want to make a `TabItem` component that's just a `div`, it's as easy as `const TabItem = 'div';`

Comment: You want "a Component in React that renders nothing and performs no logic" yet clearly share a component that in fact *does* render *something*. IMO if it is *just* a div and nothing else, then for readability/maintainability/sanity reason it *should* absolutely be left a "div". HTML elements already allow for `id`s and `classes` to help identify them and if named appropriately enough, their purpose. It is literally just as good as creating a custom component just for the name (likely better for the reasons just listed). I'm voting to close as too broad and opinionated.